# Redirect domains to path on main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some domains:

- `http://domainmain.com`
- `http://domainone.com`
- `http://domaintwo.com`

My secondary domains are currently hosted under the main domain. No sub-directories, no other paths. So every domain get the contents of `http://domainmain.com`.

*For better understanding: These files points all to the same file: `http://domainmain.com/index.php`,  `http://domainone.com/index.php`,  `http://domaintwo.com/index.php`.*

For every domain I have a folder located at `http://domainmain.com`:

```
domainname       folder / path
--------------   -----------
domainmain.com   /
domainone.com    /domainone
domaintwo.com    /domaintwo
```

My goal is to redirect every domain to the corresponding dir / path `http://domainone.com`.

For example: `http://domainone.com` has to show the content of path `/domainone`. The visiter has to see `http://domainone.com`. This also should work: `http://domaintwo.com/images` shows `http://domainmain.com/images`.

---

Some code I started with in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainone.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domainone
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domainone/$1 [NC,L]
```

And some PHP (but I want to use redirect instead of `file_get_contents()`:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'domaintwo.com') {
    echo file_get_contents('http://domainmain.com/domaintwo');
    die();
}
```

---

*Note: It is only possible to have an `.htaccess` file at `http://domainmain.com`. My server runs PHP5.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite similar to this one asked on the web-master's section;

[How to redirect different domains to separate subdirectories.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/39868/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-rewrite-different-domains-to-different-sub-directorie)

Comment: My domains point to my main domain, but not to sub-directories. When I use the code mentioned I get this in my log: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Comment: I am a little unclear what you want, and you don't say what URL you used in above comment. Are you saying; my secondary domains are currently hosted in sub-directories under the main domain. If this is the case, then you want two .htaccess file one ineach of the secondary doman directories that redirect to the main domain directory.

Comment: My secondary domains are currently hosted under the main domain. No sub-directories, no other paths.

Comment: I had some interfering code: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(api/.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) website.php?path=$1 [L]`, it's solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domainone)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^domainone(/.*|)$)^.*$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domaintwo)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^domaintwo(/.*|)$)^.*$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```